# Toggle Nav Menu on and off and close other nav menus on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried several different venues and ultimately came back to this which allows me to toggle them on and off individually but also I can open one dropdown and then also open another dropdown without the first closing. I want to be able to toggle them on and off as well as close all others when one is toggled on.

```
$('.list > li a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide any working JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide all other elements first and then toggle current element.

```
$('.list > li a').click(function () {
    $('.list > li a').not(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do what you are doing there with a logical operator. This is brilliant. ++

Comment: This issue pulling a tag into the code is you need to exactly click on the a element, not a bit outside a element. In practical case, highlighting li tag parent element with a will make coding more. So its advisable to detect the click on  li and toggle off.

Answer (score 2):

Hide all toggles first and then show which is clicked.

Note: I have removed the `<a>` tag and took the click on to the `<li>` element itself:

```
$('.list > li').click(function () {
    $('.list  li').hide();
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```